# getLocationOnScreen() returns unexpected values

Tags: android, view

I have a toolbar in my app with a search icon.
Tapping the search icon opens a search layout (FrameLayout).

I'm trying to add a circular reveal animation that will start at the center of the tapped icon.
To find the icon coordinates I'm using getLocationOnScreen() and later calculate the center using its width and height.

Calling getLocationOnScreen() on the search icon view (a menu item) returns the center left point:
[image]

Calling getLocationOnScreen() on the X (close) icon or the back icon returns the bottom left point:
[image]

I thought it's supposed to return the top left corner, any ideas?